# Stuck on expected value division

Tags: probability

Assume X and Y are independent discrete random variables.
Assume Y takes only positive numbers is it true that:

E[x/y]=E[x]/E[y]

or is it true that

E[x/y]=E[x]*E[1/y]

(if yes, present a proof,
if not show a counterexample)

Sorry did not post my work, but did not have time.

I have that E[x/y] does not equal E[x}/E[y]

E[X/Y] = E[X* 1/Y]
       = E[X] * E[1/Y]
       = E[X] * 1/E[Y] 
       =E[X]/E[Y]
Poof is wrong since E[1/Y] does not equal 1/E[Y]
COUNTER EXAMPLE EX: P[Y=1]=.5, P[Y=2] =.5
E[Y]= 1.5 AND  1/E[Y] =.666  ALSO E[1/Y]=.75 WHICH DOES NOT EQUAL 1/E[1/Y]

PROOF FOR E[x/y]=E[x]*E[1/y]

E[X/Y]= E[X* 1/Y]
      = E[X]* E[1/Y]

Comment: I posted my work and analysis. Sorry I didn't post earlier, but it was late and I did not have time to type it all out.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb E[X/Y]$ may not exist, but if it does exist it is $E[X] E[1/Y]$.